# How to collapse a recursive tree in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I have a tree type:

```
type tree = Vertex of int * tree list;;
```

My recursive equality definition is that two trees are equal if their ints are equal and all of their children are equal.

How do I build the function

```
topo: tree -> tree list
```

that creates a list of all of the trees in depth first search order with each tree appearing once and only once (according to the equality definition)? I want to do this in a computationally efficient way. Maybe use lazy or a hashmap?

Here is my attempt, the code blows up when the length is too large:

```
type tree = Vertex of int * (tree list)

let rec base = function
    | 0 -> Vertex (0, [])
    | i -> Vertex (i, [base (i - 1)])

let rec range = function
    | 0 -> [0]
    | i -> i :: range (i - 1)

let agg i = Vertex (-1, List.map base (range i))

let rec equals (a: tree) (b: tree) : bool =
    let rec deep_match a_dep b_dep = match a_dep, b_dep with
        | [], []       -> true
        | [], _
        | _, []        -> false
        | x::xs, y::ys -> equals x y && deep_match xs ys
    in
    let Vertex (ai, al) = a in
    let Vertex (bi, bl) = b in
    ai = bi && deep_match al bl

let rec in_list (a: tree) (l: tree list) : bool = match l with
    | [] -> false
    | hd::tl -> equals a hd || in_list a tl

let rec topological (pool: tree list) (t: tree) : tree list =
    if in_list t pool then pool else
        t::match t with
            | Vertex(_, []) -> pool
            | Vertex(_, deps) -> List.fold_left topological pool deps

let big_agg = agg 100_000
let topo_ordered = topological [] big_agg;;
Printf.printf "len %i\n" (List.length topo_ordered)
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself, and where did you get stuck? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, but a place to get help with _specific_ programming problems. See [ask] and what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: I tried looking into how to do this lazily and also doing this with a hash map, but I got stuck. It seems like an easy problem in C: return pointers and memoize the most recursive generators of trees. Then collapse with a dictionary that uses pointers. I don’t see how to do something similar in OCaml

Comment: Can you explain what _specific_ issue you encountered trying to implement it? "I don’t see how..." is not what I would consider specific. Neither is "I got stuck".

Comment: So suppose my DAG has n “base” nodes and one “parent node”. Let’s say there’s an edge from base n to base n - 1,  down to base 0 which has no edges. Then let’s say there’s an edge from parent to every base node. Even though this graph only has n + 1 vertices and 2n - 1 edges, the number of paths grows with n ^ 2.

When I try to write this function with the direct equality operator, the time the program takes to complete blows up and you can’t evaluate it with say n=100000.

Comment: Can you update the question with that? And preferably illustrate with an example, or even a [mcve]. I think that would make this a pretty good question.

Comment: I've added my attempt!

Comment: I don't know OCaml. However, I don't think that is what is stopping me from implementing this in a functional programming language. The problem you are running into has to do with the size of the tree to be traversed. In other words, you need scale the problem out to more threads if you want to run it in a reasonable amount of time. I have an idea of how to do this in Scala and Akka, using the actor model. But that is not OCaml.

Comment: The size of the tree is linear in the agg parameter so your statement is incorrect. I know how to write the C code to accomplish this in linear time for example.

Comment: I was addressing the comment you made that begins, "So suppose my DAG has ..." Your depth first search may be able to traverse the tree in linear time, but you seem to be saying in your comment (correct me if I am wrong) that it takes an unacceptably long time. I was simply saying there is a way to traverse the tree in sub-linear time using parallelism.

Comment: The problem I’m asking about has nothing to do with parallelism. The problem is that crawling the tree as the code is written taken much more than linear time. The goal is to find a way to write the code in OCaml such that it takes only linear time.

Comment: I just want to say I was not the one who downvoted your question. I don't know why my comment was deleted, but I was trying to say that you are free to use whatever abstraction model or programming language you want to solve your problem. It wasn't clear to me if a solution had to be written in OCaml, which was why I made my comment. Since I know now, I hope you find the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it efficient you need to implement ordering and hash-consing. With total ordering, you can store your trees in a balanced tree or even a hashtable, thus turning your `in_list` into O(logN) or even O(1). Adding hash-consing will enable O(1) comparison of your trees (at the cost of less efficient tree construction).

Instead of having both, depending on your design constraints, you can have only one. For the didactic purposes, let's implement hash-consing for your particular representation

To implement hash-consing you need to make your constructor private and hide data constructors behind an abstraction wall (to prevent users from breaking you hash-consing properties):

```
module Tree : sig
  type t = private Vertex of int * t list

  val create : int -> t list -> t
  val equal : t -> t -> bool
end  = struct
  type t = Vertex of int * t list

  let repository = Hashtbl.create 64

  let create n children =
    let node = Vertex (n,children) in
    try Hashtbl.find repository node
    with Not_found -> Hashtbl.add repository node node; node
  let equal x y = x == y
end
```

Since we guaranteed that structurally equal trees are physically equal during the tree creation (i.e., if there exists an equal tree in our repository then we return it), we are now able to substitute structural equality with physical equality, i.e., with pointer comparison.

We got a fast comparison with the price - we now leaking memory, since we need to store all ever created trees and the create function is now O(N). We can alleviate the first problem by using ephemerons, but the latter problem will persist, of course.

Another issue, is that we're not able to put our trees into ordered structure, like a map or a set. We can of course use regular polymorphic compare, but since it will be O(N), inserting to such structure will become quadratic. Not an option for us. Therefore we need to add total ordering on our trees. We can theoretically do this without changing the representation (using ephemerons), but it is easier just to add an order parameter to our tree representation, e.g.,

```
module Tree : sig
  type order (* = private int *) (* add this for debuggin *)
  type t = private Vertex of order * int * t list

  val create : int -> t list -> t
  val equal : t -> t -> bool
  val compare : t -> t -> int
end = struct
  type order = int
  type t = Vertex of order * int * t list
  type tree = t

  module Repository = Hashtbl.Make(struct
      type t = tree
      let max_hash = 16

      let rec equal (Vertex (_,p1,x)) (Vertex (_,p2,y)) =
        match compare p1 p2 with
        | 0 -> equal_trees x y
        | n -> false
      and equal_trees xs ys = match xs, ys with
        | [],[] -> true
        | [],_ | _,[] -> false
        | x :: xs, y::ys -> equal x y && equal_trees xs ys
      let rec hash (Vertex (_,p,xs)) =
        hash_trees (Hashtbl.hash p) max_hash xs
      and hash_trees hash depth = function
        | x :: xs when depth > 0 ->
          hash_trees (Hashtbl.hash x) (depth-1) xs
        | _ -> hash
    end)

  let repository = Repository.create 64

  let create n children =
    try Repository.find repository (Vertex (0,n,children))
    with Not_found ->
      let order = Repository.length repository + 1 in
      let node = Vertex (order,n,children) in
      Repository.add repository node node; node

  let equal x y = x == y
  let order (Vertex (order,_,_)) = order
  let compare x y = compare (order x) (order y)

end
```

We had to manually implement the structural variants of `equal` and `hash` for our trees because we need to ignore the order in comparison, when we store a new tree in the repository. It looks like a bit of work, but in the real-life you can do this using derivers.

Anyways, now we got a comparable version of a tree with a comparison function which is O(1), so we can put our trees in sets and maps, and implement your topo efficiently.

A nice feature of both implementations is a tight representation of a tree, since sharing is guaranteed by the `create` function. E.g.,

```
# let t1 = Tree.create 42 [];;
val t1 : Tree.t = Tree.Vertex (1, 42, [])
# let t3 = Tree.create 42 [t1; t1];;
val t3 : Tree.t =
  Tree.Vertex (2, 42, [Tree.Vertex (1, 42, []); Tree.Vertex (1, 42, [])])
# let t5 = Tree.create 42 [t1; t3; t1];;
val t5 : Tree.t =
  Tree.Vertex (3, 42,
   [Tree.Vertex (1, 42, []);
    Tree.Vertex (2, 42, [Tree.Vertex (1, 42, []); Tree.Vertex (1, 42, [])]);
    Tree.Vertex (1, 42, [])])
#
```

In this example, `t1` in `t5` and `t3` will be the same pointer.

Answer (score 2):

For optimal performance, one possibility would be to use [hashconsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_consing). However, in your current example, both the generation and the unicity test are quadratic in `n`. Fixing both points seems to already improve performance a lot.

First, we can avoid the quadratic tree generation by adding a lot of sharing:

```
let range max =
  let rec range elt l n =
    if n > max then elt::l
    else
      let next = Vertex(n,[elt]) in
      range next (elt::l) (n+1) in
  range (Vertex(0,[])) [] 1

let agg i = Vertex (-1, range i)
```

With this change, it is become reasonable to generate a tree with 10<sup>10</sup> elements (but only 10<sup>5</sup> unique elements).
Then, the unicity test can be done with a set (or a hashtable):

```
module S = Set.Make(struct type t = tree let compare = compare end)

let rec topological (set, pool) t =
    if S.mem t set then (set, pool) else
      let set = S.add t set in
      let set, pool =
        match t with
        | Vertex(_, []) -> set, pool
        | Vertex(_, deps) -> List.fold_left topological (set,pool) deps in
      set, t::pool
```

Comment: Just to make it explicit, since `compare` is O(N) in the size of the tree, the `Set.add` function will be O(N^2) and `topological` is O(N^3). It is probably better to use the original `in_list`. It is also O(N^2) but with smaller constant factor (and better memory representation).

Comment: The comparison function is certainly misbehaved in this case, but since the height of the tree of the set is in ln(N), shouldn't the insertion of Set.add in `O(N ln N)`? And empirically using `Set` does speed up the execution (by a factor 200).

Comment: The speedup is due to the sharing since polymorphic comparison looks for physical identity before recursing deeper and an accidental ordering of data :) The insertion in your case is `N* N * log N`, which is `O(N^2)`. To insert an element into the list you need to do `O(N*logN)` comparisons, where each comparison takes `O(N)`, thus `O(N) * O(N*logN) = O(N^2)`. `Set.mem` gives us `O(logN)` comparisons, which each comparison having `O(N)`, so in total `O(N*logN)` which subsumed by insertion. Finally, `topological` does `N` insertions, so it is `O(N)*O(N^2) = O(N^3)`

Comment: Ah right, the cost is dominated by recognizing equal terms in this case, thus it is indeed the physical equality shortcut that matters. I am still not sure where does the N ln N comparisons by insertion comes from however? You would have to sort from scratch the whole tree to do that many comparisons? And for readers, the proposed answer by @ivg is much better.

Comment: Oh sorry, of course the insertion is only `O(logN)`, inserting all trees from the list, will  take `O(NlogN)` comparisons, each `O(N)` itself, so that both the complexity of `topological` and `S.add` will be bounded by `O(N^2)`, not `O(N^3)`.